# Desarrollo Gráfica con MPAndroidChart Android

Tags: java, android

Estoy tratando de realizar una gráfica  en android con la librería MPAndroidChart [MPANDROIDCHART](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). Mi problema es que al insertar los datos, siguiendo el ejemplo, me manda un error. No consigo dilucidar cual es el problema. Inserto imagen:
Por cierto,  utilizo el patrón ViewHolder ya que es necesario para mostrar una lista de cardViews.
[image: En todo momento estoy siguiendo los pasos de la librería.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según veo los constructores de `LineDate` son estos:

```
LineData() 
LineData(java.util.List<java.lang.String> xVals) 
LineData(java.util.List<java.lang.String> xVals, ILineDataSet dataSet) 
LineData(java.util.List<java.lang.String> xVals, java.util.List<ILineDataSet> dataSets) 
LineData(java.lang.String[] xVals) 
LineData(java.lang.String[] xVals, ILineDataSet dataSet) 
LineData(java.lang.String[] xVals, java.util.List<ILineDataSet> dataSets)
```

Y pareciera que tu lo haces bien. Sin embargo los ejemplos de la librería muestran que en vez de la interfaz pura `ILineDataSet`, usan la implementación `LineDataSet`.

¿Has probado de esa forma?